# Is there a Container only distribution for Spring XD?

Tags: spring, spring-xd

When running Spring XD in [Distributed Mode](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/current/reference/html/#running-distributed-mode), there will be many JVM's running the XD Container.

Is there a "slimmed down" version of the XD distribution that includes only the bins/libs that are necessary to run the container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there currently isn't. But I'm not 100% sure the container-only version would be that slim (it's the container that needs to know about the many frameworks supported). So if we ever hard-separate the two, I'd bet that the *admin* would benefit.

If this is really a concern for you, I'd invite you to create a JIRA issue to track this (ideally motivating the concern). We always aim for better modularity, but this hasn't been on the top of our list, for now.